# custom layout when sony smart watch 2 is locked(watchfaces)

Tags: android, android-layout, push-notification, sony, sony-smartwatch

I am working on android app. Now when the app get notification my sony smart watch 2 also get notified of that.But now i wanted to have full screen notification when app is locked similar like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nefastudio.android.smartwatch2.nfwatchfaces) app. This app show custom ui when app is locked. So how can i get this thing done. Is there any class or method that can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial on how to develop watchfaces for SW2:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/2014/05/27/develop-clocks-and-widgets-for-smartwatch-2-with-the-new-widget-api-tutorial/